# Is there any isMember kind of method for Objective-C int array?

Tags: ios, objective-c, arrays, nsarray

Is there any isMember kind of method for Objective-C int array?

What i mean, how can i get a BOOL value with one-line control whether myMethod's parameter is in or out of myArray?

```
@implementation myController

int counter;
int *myArray[10] = {2,3,9,10,11,15,16,17,18,25};

- (id) init {


    if (self = [super init]) {

    }
    return self;

}

- (void)myMethod:x:(int)x
{
    if (myArray.isMember(x) ) {
        <#statements#>
    }
    else {
        <#some other statements#>
    }
}
```

Comment: `myArray` is not a Objective-C array, it's a C array.

Comment: By the way, the array stores `int *`, may be it's not what you want.

Comment: you don't actually need _a pointer to a pointer to an array_ like this `*myArray[10]`, do you? btw, why don't you use `NSArray<NSNumber> *` instead? there are tons of high-level methods of an `NSArray` which helps you to deal with the elements; see __[docs](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSArray_Class/)__.

Comment: i know NSArray. I was just toying around with Objective-C.
int *  was exactly what i wanted.

Thanks for reply though..

Answer (score 0):

Like this

```
NSArray * array = @[@1, @2, @3, @4];
if ([array containsObject:@1]) // will return true
if ([array containsObject:@5]) // will return false
```